# Can't make a simple php - Ajax working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

I want to build a simple contact form using Jquery with an ajax call and PHP. 
But it does not work and I cannot see why. You can consider that there are no mistake of id's or class name.

**My Javascript**

```
 jQuery('#contacter').click(function () {       

        var postdata = $('.contact-form form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: postdata,
            success: function () {

                $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $('.contact-form').append('<p>Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you very soon.</p>');


                });

            }
        });


    });
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php

// Enter the email where you want to receive the message
$emailTo = 'example@gmail.com';

$clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
$subject = addslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
$message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
$antispam = addslashes(trim($_POST['antispam']));


$headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
mail($emailTo, $subject , $message, $headers);

?>
```

My site refreshes with no mail sent. I already tested my server with a simple mail() and it works fine : no problem on the server side.

Comment: Any errors in developers console?

Comment: If your site is refreshing, I suspect your form is submitting, when you should prevent its' default action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to me is postback happens when form gets submitted. As you are using a `click` event on a button *(assumption)* and its default behavior is to submit the form and that results in a postback.

As you are using ajax to submit values to backend so you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the *form submission/default behavior*.

You have to stop the event with `event.preventDefault()`:

```
 jQuery('#contacter').click(function (e) {  // <-----pass e for event here    
    e.preventDefault(); // and stop it here
```

and if you are working with `form` element then better to go with `submit` event instead:

```js
jQuery('.contact-form form').submit(function(e) { // e in the args
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission here.
  var postdata = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'contact.php',
    data: postdata,
    success: function() {
      $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('.contact-form').append('<p>Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you very soon.</p>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked : the animation shows up which mean the php script runs well. But ... I don't receive any mail (of course I changed the mail to a real one in the php.) Any idea ?